# Read the content of the file, count the number of letters 'y' and 'z' and display the values on the screen

Tags: assembly, x86

Read the content of the file, count the number of letters 'y' and 'z' and display the values on the screen.

For some reason the register that counts the z's doesn't increase at all. Could someone help me find what I'm missing? The one for y's does increase, but the register that counts the z's (edx) remains 0 and can't see why.

```
global start    

extern exit,fopen,fclose,fread  ,printf          
import exit msvcrt.dll 
import fopen msvcrt.dll
import fclose msvcrt.dll
import fread msvcrt.dll 
import printf msvcrt.dll 

segment data use32 class=data
    file_name db "input.txt", 0  ; the name of the file that's gonna be read
    mod_acces db "r", 0
    descriptor dd -1
    len equ 100  ; the maximum length that can be read in the current stage
    buffer times len db 0
    nr_of_chars_read dd 0
    format_print db "The number of 'y' is %d and 'z' is %d.", 0

segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        push dword mod_acces
        push dword file_name
        call [fopen]
        add esp, 4*2  ; free parameters on the stack
        
        cmp eax, 0
        je final
        
        mov [descriptor], eax
        
        loop_:
            push dword [descriptor]
            push dword len
            push dword 1
            push dword buffer
            call [fread]
            add esp, 4*4  ; free parameters on the stack
            
            cmp eax, 0  ; if eax is 0, then we finished reading the file
            je cleanup

            mov [nr_of_chars_read], eax  ; saving the number of characters read
            
            mov ecx, [nr_of_chars_read]
            cld
            cmp ecx, 0
            je cleanup
            
            mov ebx, 0  ; in ebx we'll store the number of y's
            mov edx, 0  ; in edx we'll store the number of z's
            
            mov esi, 0
            
            check_character:
                ; push ecx
                mov al, byte [buffer + esi]
                
                cmp al, 'y'  ; check if it is y
                je found_y
                
                jg is_z
                
                is_z:
                    cmp al, 'z'  ; check if it is z
                    je found_z
                
                jmp next
                
                found_y:
                    inc ebx  ; incrementing the counter for y
                    jmp next

                found_z:
                    inc edx  ; incrementing the counter for z
                    jmp next
                    
                next:
                    ;pop ecx
                    inc esi  ; go to the next character from buffer
                    loop check_character
            
            jmp loop_
            
        cleanup:
       
        ; printing the number of y's and z's
        
        push edx
        push ebx
        push dword format_print
        call [printf]
        add esp, 4*2
        
        ; closing the file
        
        push dword [descriptor]
        call [fclose]
        add esp, 4
        
        final:
        push    dword 0      ; push the parameter for exit onto the stack
        call    [exit]       ; call exit to terminate the program
```

Is it something wrong with the code or the displaying message?

Comment: Two things: a) set the counters to 0 outside the outer loop so they aren’t cleared after each line of the file. b) ebx is preserved by fread but edx isn’t. I suggest using ebp instead of edx. Ebp is also preserved across function calls.

Comment: @prl Thank you! I changed it according to your suggestion and it works just fine!